# Set-Cookie is not been set (local DEV environment)

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers, chalice

This is yet another question about set-cookie on localhost. I am facing the same problem as many others here when it comes to the usage of cookies on localhost.
This is my setup:

- I am running a reactjs app locally on a url like "https://app.web.product". My hosts file points all requests form app.web.product to 127.0.0.1.
- My REST service is hosted on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (using AWS chalice). Each response returns the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://app.web.product" to ensure that the requests go through from my web app.
- The REST services returns as well the header "Set-Cookie: name=value; domain=app.web.product", however, the cookie never gets persisted. I tried in all browsers. In Edge/IE I can at least see in the response header that cookie is been recognized. In Chrome the set-cookie response header is not even been displayed.

I've tried to run my REST service on https and same domain name as the web app just with different port. However, for some reason AWS chalice does not let me run https properly. However, I don't think this will solve the issue so I stopped investigating further.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So basically, the problem was that Chrome never displayed the cookie in the developer tools. Maybe because the cookie belonged to the server address (127.0.0.1) and not to the domain where my reactjs app was running (app.web.product). 
Nevertheless, when I clicked on the info icon on the left hand side of the address bar next to the URL, I did see the cookie! The only remaining thing I had to do is to set the path in the cookie to "/" and that was it.